# MBProgressHUD activity indicator doesn't show in viewDidAppear after segue is performed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mbprogresshud

I have two `UITableViewControllers` A and B, and this is what I'm trying to do when I click on a table view cell in A:

1. Prepare to segue from A to B by setting some of B's variables from A.
2. Perform segue from A to B.
3. B appears.
4. Display a "Loading" activity indicator with `[MBProgressHUD][1]`.
5. In a background task, retrieve data from a URL.
6. If an error occurs in the URL request (either no data received or non-200 status code), (a) hide activity indicator, then (b) display UIAlertView with an error message
7. Else, (a) Reload B's `tableView` with the retrieved data, then (b) Hide activity indicator

However, this is what's happening, and I don't know how to fix it:

1. After clicking a cell in A, B slides in from the right with an empty plain `UITableView`. The `MBProgressHUD` **DOES NOT SHOW**.
2. After a while, the `tableView` reloads with the retrieved data, with the `MBProgressHUD` appearing very briefly.
3. The `MBProgressHUD` immediately disappears.

There doesn't seem to be an error with the way the background task is performed. My problem is, how do I display the `MBProgressHUD` activity indicator as soon as my B view controller appears? (And actually, how come it's not showing?) Code is below.

`A`'s prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    B *b = (B *)[segue destinationViewController];

    // Set some of B's variables here...
}
```

Relevant methods in `B`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startOver];
}

- (void)startOver {
    [self displayLoadingAndDisableTableViewInteractions];
    [self retrieveListings];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self hideLoadingAndEnableTableViewInteractions];
}

- (void)displayLoadingAndDisableTableViewInteractions {
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)hideLoadingAndEnableTableViewInteractions {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)retrieveListings {
    __block NSArray *newSearchResults;

    // Perform synchronous URL request in another thread.
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        newSearchResults = [self fetchNewSearchResults];
    });

    // If nil was returned, there must have been some error--display a UIAlertView.
    if (newSearchResults == nil) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"An unknown error occurred. Try again later?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    } else {
        // Add the retrieved data to this UITableView's model. Then,
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)fetchNewSearchResults {
    // Assemble NSMutableArray called newSearchResults from NSURLConnection data.
    // Return nil if an error or a non-200 response code occurred.
    return newSearchResults;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `B` appears, it displays a plain and empty `UITableView`, but does not display the `MBProgressHUD` even if the task does begin in the background (and yet, the `MBProgressHUD` is called to show before that). Hence, my solution is to show the `MBProgressHUD` in `viewDidLoad`, which precedes `viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    [self displayLoadingAndDisableUI];
}
```

I set up two additional boolean properties to `B`--one in .h, called `shouldStartOverUponAppearing`, and one in a class extension in .m, called `isLoadingAndDisabledUI`. In `startOver`, I added the following lines:

```
- (void)startOver {
    if (!self.isLoadingAndDisabledUI) {
        [self displayLoadingAndDisabledUI];
    }
}
```

The check is done so that `startOver` doesn't display another `MBProgressHUD` when it has already been displayed from `viewDidLoad`. That is because I have a third view controller, called `C`, that may call on `B`'s `startOver`, but doesn't need to call `viewDidLoad` just to display the `MBProgressHUD`.

Also, this is how I defined `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.shouldStartOverUponAppearing) {
        [self startOver];
        self.shouldStartOverUponAppearing = NO;
    }
}
```

This way, `startOver` will only be invoked IF `B` appeared from A. If `B` appears by pressing "Back" in `C`, it will do nothing and only display the old data that was there.

I think that this solution is **FAR** from elegant, but it works. I guess I'll just ask for a better approach in a separate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you have to call `[self hideLoadingAndEnableTableViewInteractions];` after `newSearchResults = [self fetchNewSearchResults];` You are retrieving data in another thread which means `-startOver` will continue executing after calling `[self retrieveListings];` and will hide the HUD right away.  Also because you are updating the display you have to make sure you are doing that on the main thread. See example

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //update UI here
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look through my code. Will `startOver` really continue executing even when `retrieveListings` is not yet done, though? Because the reason why I used `dispatch_sync` to get the `newSearchResults` from `fetchNewSearchResults` is so that I'll wait for that background thread to finish before proceeding with the next statements. If I used `dispatch_async`, however, then it would behave as you are saying.

Comment: I didn't realize that 'dispatch_sync' would wait for the fetch to finish loading to proceed .  If you don't mind me asking but why not use dispatch_async?  hud will block the user interaction until the data will load and the UI will not be frozen and you don't have to use so many extra steps to get it working.

Comment: Because when I call on HUD's `showHUDAddedTo:` method and pass `self.view`, which is a `UITableView`, the activity indicator shows on top of the `UITableView` **BUT** the table view remains scrollable and the HUD goes along with it. Also, I have to wait for the retrieval process to return because if I didn't get any, I have to show a `UIAlertView`--my next actions are conditonal, in short.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a common method for MBProgressHUD.

1. **#import "MBProgressHUD.h"** in **AppDelegate.h** also following methods.

   ```
   - (MBProgressHUD *)showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
   - (void)dismissGlobalHUD;
   ```
2. In AppDelegate.m add following methods.

   ```
   - (MBProgressHUD *)showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
      [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.window animated:YES];
      MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.window animated:YES];
      hud.labelText = title;
      return hud;
   }

   - (void)dismissGlobalHUD {
     [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.window animated:YES];
   }
   ```
3. How to use?

   ```
   AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   //Show Indicator
   [appDel showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"Loading..."];
   //Hide Indicator
   [appDel dismissGlobalHUD];
   ```

Hope this helps.